# Angular build command options

Tags: angular

In the official Ng-Book about Angular 6 I read that it is possible build an app via the command

```
ng build --target=production --base-href /
```

But, if I try it in a very simple app which normally builds perfectly, I see the message

```
unknow option: '--target'
```

Why? (the book and my app are obviously referred to the same Angular version, the 6)

Comment: Because the CLI has changed since the time the book has been written. But the proper command to build for production has never been `ng build --target=production`. It has always been `ng build --prod`.

Comment: Super! Thanks, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an error in the book and has been corrected in Revision 69 https://www.ng-book.com/2/p/Changelog/

Should be

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: Super! Thanks for your answer